# Mongoose limit one of multiple populated fields

Tags: mongoose, database-design

Friends is an array with pictures as a nested array. How do I limit the number of pictures returned in my query?

```
const foundUser = await User.findOne({ username: username })
      .populate('friends', 'first_name last_name pictures')
```

Edit:
Wording and My solution so far:

```
let foundUser = await User.findOne({ username: username })
  .populate('friends', 'first_name last_name pictures')
  .lean();
foundUser.friends = foundUser.friends.map(friend => {
  return {
    ...friend,
    pictures: friend.pictures.slice(0, limit),
  };
});
```

However, I'm still interested in a solution which handles limiting the nested pictures array within the query call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const foundUser = await User.findOne({ username: username })
      .populate('friends', 'first_name last_name pictures')
      .then((res) => {
         let response = res;
         res.friends.forEach((friend, index)=>
            response.friends[index].pictures = friend.pictures.slice(0, limit)
         )
         return response;
      })
```

This may be helpful for you.

If you are going to use pagination, the slice method can be designed as ;

```js
response.friends[index].pictures = friend.pictures.slice(((page-1) * limit), limit);
```